# How to calculate difficulty of genesis block?

Tags: blockchain, mining, difficulty

To calculate difficulty of a block we need the parent block timestamp and difficulty? As there doesn't exist a parent block so what values should we take for those?

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty for the genesis block, along with all the other parameters, is **hard coded** into the Ethereum clients. It is not calculated. More information about genesis block can be found [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/27/final-steps/).

> The Genesis block is pretty much a database file: it contains all the transactions from the Ether sale, and when a user inputs it into the client, it represents their decision to join the network under its terms: it is the first step to consensus.

Comment: I know that. What I want to know is where from did they get those hardcoded values? Parent hash can be 0 but what about parent timestamp? If I use 0 as parent timestamp than difficulty will be too easy.

Comment: update here link as it is 2015 blog